# Win 7 API to set power key to sleep rather than shutdown

Tags: windows, api

What are the Windows 7 API calls to cause the power key to sleep rather than shutdown?

I do not need advice about how to use the Windows Control Panel.  This is a programming question.

How would one write code to do this?

Answer (score 1):

[This MSDN forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/tabletandtouch/thread/99f51cf5-dbc5-4caf-9356-6b720e2a0d3a) has the exact same question with the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks!  Do you think that Win 7 and Vista would be similar in this regard?

Comment: @jon Identical from an API perspective.